# How to transform a list of list of dynamic in dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Any help how to resolve this in dart would be great.
I am parsing a csv file which returns a list of list dynamic.

```
List<List<dynamic>> stores = [
  // id - Store - Store Address - Invoice reference - invoice amount - Due Date

  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '1ST STREET STORE', 'XT1016165', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '1ST STREET STORE', 'XT1016167', -2782.5, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '53TH AVENUE STORE', 'XT1016046', -1856.51, 02/05/2021], 
  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '53TH AVENUE STORE', 'XT1016164', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', '124TH ST STORE', 'XT1016165', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', '124TH ST STORE', 'XT1016167',  -2782.5, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', 'STORE 73', 'XT1016046',  -1856.51, 02/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', 'STORE 73', 'XT1016164', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', 'STORE 73', 'XT1016164',  -3310.19, 08/05/2021], 
];
```

How can I parse the list above to get the result below, knowing that there's a big list of stores.
The idea is to combine every store that shares the same id to a new list.

```
List<dynamic> PAULS = [
  // id - Store - Store Address - Invoice reference - invoice amount - Due Date
  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '1ST STREET STORE', 'XT1016165', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '1ST STREET STORE', 'XT1016167', -2782.5, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '53TH AVENUE STORE', 'XT1016046', -1856.51, 02/05/2021], 
];

List<dynamic> SAPHYR = [
  // id - Store - Store Address - Invoice reference - invoice amount - Due Date
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', '124TH ST STORE', 'XT1016165', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', '124TH ST STORE', 'XT1016167',  -2782.5, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', 'STORE 73', 'XT1016046',  -1856.51, 02/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', 'STORE 73', 'XT1016164', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', 'STORE 73', 'XT1016164',  -3310.19, 08/05/2021], 
];
```

Comment: `List<dynamic> PAULS = stores.where((data) => data[1] == "PAULS").toList();`

Comment: but how to do it dynamically without hard code every store? There's 200 rows

Comment: Sorry, I've added an answer. See if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```dart
Map<K, List<dynamic>> groupBy<K>(List<List<dynamic>> stores) {
  return stores.fold({}, (map, element) {
    return map..putIfAbsent(element[1], () => []).add(element);
  });
}
```

Use it like this:

```dart
List<List<dynamic>> stores = [
  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '1ST STREET STORE', 'XT1016165', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '1ST STREET STORE', 'XT1016167', -2782.5, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '53TH AVENUE STORE', 'XT1016046', -1856.51, 02/05/2021], 
  ['C000015', 'PAULS', '53TH AVENUE STORE', 'XT1016164', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', '124TH ST STORE', 'XT1016165', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', '124TH ST STORE', 'XT1016167',  -2782.5, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', 'STORE 73', 'XT1016046',  -1856.51, 02/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', 'STORE 73', 'XT1016164', -3230.19, 08/05/2021], 
  ['C000066', 'SAPHYR', 'STORE 73', 'XT1016164',  -3310.19, 08/05/2021], 
];

print(groupBy(stores));
```

The output is a map where which key is the store name and its value the store list.

```
{
  "PAULS": [
    ["C000015", "PAULS", "1ST STREET STORE", "XT1016165", -3230.19, "08/05/2021"],
    ["C000015", "PAULS", "1ST STREET STORE", "XT1016167", -2782.5, "08/05/2021"],
    ["C000015", "PAULS", "53TH AVENUE STORE", "XT1016046", -1856.51, "02/05/2021"],
    ["C000015", "PAULS", "53TH AVENUE STORE", "XT1016164", -3230.19, "08/05/2021"]
  ],
  "SAPHYR": [
    ["C000066", "SAPHYR", "124TH ST STORE", "XT1016165", -3230.19, "08/05/2021"],
    ["C000066", "SAPHYR", "124TH ST STORE", "XT1016167", -2782.5, "08/05/2021"],
    ["C000066", "SAPHYR", "STORE 73", "XT1016046", -1856.51, "02/05/2021"],
    ["C000066", "SAPHYR", "STORE 73", "XT1016164", -3230.19, "08/05/2021"],
    ["C000066", "SAPHYR", "STORE 73", "XT1016164", -3310.19, "08/05/2021"],
  ]
}
```